# How to count the values of a pandas groupby that meet a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, group-by

Before I start, I want to make it clear that my question is different than [Counting values that meet a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807845/counting-values-that-meet-a-condition) and [Want to count the number of values in a column that meet a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093043/want-to-count-the-number-of-values-in-a-column-that-meet-a-condition).

Allow me to explain. Here is my df:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'name':['joe','dan','betty','joe','dan','betty','joe','dan','betty','joe','dan','betty'],'points':[12,3,5,10,5,16,2,8,15,17,1,3]})
test


   name points
0   joe   12
1   dan    3
2   betty  5
3   joe   10
4   dan    5
5   betty 16
6   joe    2
7   dan    8
8   betty 15
9   joe   17
10  dan    1
11  betty  3
```

What I am aiming to do is count how many times each person had less than 10 points and create a new column that consists of that value. I tried the following and got really close:

```
test['<10'] = test[test['points'] < 10].groupby('name')['points'].transform('count')
test


    name    points  <10
0   joe       12    NaN
1   dan        3    4.0
2   betty      5    2.0
3   joe       10    NaN
4   dan        5    4.0
5   betty     16    NaN
6   joe        2    1.0
7   dan        8    4.0
8   betty     15    NaN
9   joe       17    NaN
10  dan        1    4.0
11  betty      3    2.0
```

I get the values I want, but since I subset the data frame to values <10, I am left with NaN's in the rows that were excluded. I almost have this figured out, but I would like to get those NaN values filled to show how many times each person had less than 10 points (ie joe should have 1, betty 2, and dan 4). Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: One long-routed way I can think of is renaming all Joes or Dans under 10 to Joe_1, Dan_1. Then add their occurrences. Once you have those in place of NaN, you can re-convert Dan_1 to Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code picks only rows where `point < 10`. The logic is you need to `sum` directly on the mask of `point < 10`. `True` is equivalent to `1` and  `False` is `0`. So, sum on `point < 10` will return the count of `True`. From this logic, you only need to groupby and do `transform` to populate the count of `True` to each group

```
test['<10'] = (test['points'] < 10).groupby(test['name']).transform('sum')

Out[84]:
     name  points  <10
0     joe      12  1.0
1     dan       3  4.0
2   betty       5  2.0
3     joe      10  1.0
4     dan       5  4.0
5   betty      16  2.0
6     joe       2  1.0
7     dan       8  4.0
8   betty      15  2.0
9     joe      17  1.0
10    dan       1  4.0
11  betty       3  2.0
```

Comment: Awesome, I will accept this as the correct answer when I'm able to in 5 minutes. Could you explain to me how my code and your code are different? They look almost identical.

Comment: I agree it's a great approach, but won't be intuitive to someone who is asking this type  of question.

Comment: @bismo: I added more explanation

Comment: Alien technology!

Answer (score 2):

Fix your code remove the `transform` and add `reindex`

```
test['<10']=test[test['points'] < 10].groupby('name')['points'].count().reindex(test.name).values
test
     name  points  <10
0     joe      12    1
1     dan       3    4
2   betty       5    2
3     joe      10    1
4     dan       5    4
5   betty      16    2
6     joe       2    1
7     dan       8    4
8   betty      15    2
9     joe      17    1
10    dan       1    4
11  betty       3    2
```